# What is the right way to add secondary extension to boost::filesystem::path?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I want to append additional extension to a path:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path append_extension(const fs::path& path, const fs::path& ext);
```

Expected behavior:

- append_extension("foo.txt", ".log") -> "foo.txt.log"
- append_extension("foo.txt", "log") -> "foo.txt.log"
- append_extension("foo", "log") -> "foo.log"

Is it possible to implement `append_extension` without string manipulations with dot character?

Comment: If you post "sample code" it's nice to make it syntactically correct.

Comment: does [`replace_extension`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-modifiers) help?

Comment: replace_extension doesn't preserve the 1st extension.
operator += works incorrect in case of dot absence in "ext" parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path append_extension(const fs::path& path, const fs::path& ext) {
    auto sz_ext = ext.c_str();
    if ('.' == *sz_ext) ++sz_ext;
    return path.string<std::string>() + "." + sz_ext;
}
```

> Is it possible to implement append_extension without string manipulations with dot character?

No. Extensions aren't a thing, they're merely conventions. Secondary extensions aren't even a convention, so you're on your own.

#### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f8ca523364e94e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/string_path.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path append_extension(const fs::path& path, const fs::path& ext) {
    auto sz_ext = ext.c_str();
    if ('.' == *sz_ext) ++sz_ext;
    return path.string<std::string>() + "." + sz_ext;
}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << append_extension("foo.txt", ".log") << "\n"; // -> "foo.txt.log"
    std::cout << append_extension("foo.txt", "log") << "\n"; // -> "foo.txt.log"
    std::cout << append_extension("foo", "log") << "\n"; // -> "foo.log"
}
```

Prints

```
"foo.txt.log"
"foo.txt.log"
"foo.log"
```

Comment: Your answer looks fine, but it returns an unexpected result (two consequent dots) for the 1st sample. Please notice, that for path::replace_extension method it is possible to specify extension as with dot, as without.

Comment: You're quite right. You could detect the trailing dot and inhibit the extra dot, of course. Updating the answer

Comment: I'm almost ready to accept, but could you please explain, what is the reason for `path.string<std::string>()`? Why not `path::string()`?

Comment: Yet another comment: in your implementation `path` parameter may be declared as const reference.

Comment: Yup. I had toyed with a variant that updated it inplace (using `boost::property_tree::string_path<std::string>`) but I decided against it

Comment: The reason for `string<std::string>` was (a) because I wasn't aware of the non-template overload (?) and (b) it is good to be aware of the fact that this method implies a choice